# Better performance for left transition animation with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation

This is what I have:

```css
.s2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 300ms linear;
}
```

I change the left position dynamically on scroll with JavaScript. At the moment the performance is bad on mobile and even in a desktop browser.

How can I improve this? Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Does a transition on `transform` and `transform: translateX(20px)` work better? Edit: do you really need a transition at all? That kind of transition on something that changes on scroll might not be ideal. Maybe just apply it on big scrolls.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @KoshVery i use the transition because else the element flickers on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Consider throttling the scroll using requestAnimationFrame
- use properties such as translate if you can instead of left or top
- Ad translateZ(0) or translate3d(0,0,0) to trigger GPU on mobile (not always guaranteed)

Also since you are animating during scroll, you do not need to use the transition property, unless you have breakpoints/thresholds where you set the property once scroll amount exceeds a certain value.

Comment: Or use a [throttle function (or debounce)](https://medium.com/@ellenaua/throttle-debounce-behavior-lodash-6bcae1494e03) that limits how quickly the function is fired off:

Comment: rAF does it nicely, uses microtask queue, super light and needs 0 overhead imo.